# Applying table-valued function to every value of some column in source table

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with values in one column which have to be splitted by some function, let say F. The function F takes the value and splits it into a table of values - the result is a table.

What is the most effective way to apply this function to every value of the source table and have the result table with all values splitted? I know I could use a cursor but I wonder if there exists some smarter solution?

The result should be something like:

```
SELECT F(column) FROM SourceTable
```

But this is not possible because F is table-valued.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) should do the trick.

```
SELECT *
FROM SourceTable
     CROSS APPLY F(Column)
```